# Why are there .O files in /etc/cups?

Tags: raspberry-pi, cups

I have been working on a project on a Raspberry Pi which has necessitated adding/removing printers pretty frequently (mainly because all of the drivers have issues, but that's another story).

I have noticed that in `/etc/cups` I have a lot of `.O` files which duplicate some of the other config and seem to have data from previously removed printers, none of which still exist in the cups web interface.

What are these *.o files Are they safe to remove?

```
total 92
drwxr-xr-x   5 root lp    4096 Sep 24 10:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 114 root root  4096 Sep 21 20:02 ..
-rw-------   1 root lp     108 Sep 21 16:42 classes.conf
-rw-------   1 root lp     108 Sep 21 16:25 classes.conf.O
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 16433 Jun 12  2017 cups-browsed.conf
-rw-r-----   1 root lp    3233 Sep 21 16:55 cupsd.conf
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  4629 Sep 17 15:01 cupsd.conf.O
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  2931 Jul 11 04:29 cups-files.conf
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Jul 11 04:29 interfaces
drwxr-xr-x   2 root lp    4096 Sep 24 09:26 ppd
-rw-------   1 root lp     110 Sep 24 09:27 printers.conf
-rw-------   1 root lp     483 Sep 24 06:25 printers.conf.O
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   240 Sep 17 15:01 raw.convs
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   211 Sep 17 15:01 raw.types
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   142 Jul 11 04:29 snmp.conf
drwx------   2 root lp    4096 Sep 17 15:01 ssl
-rw-r-----   1 root lp     381 Sep 24 10:01 subscriptions.conf
-rw-r-----   1 root lp      91 Sep 24 10:00 subscriptions.conf.O
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `.O` stands for `oldfile` as indicated in `cups/scheduler/file.c`:

```
oldfile[1024];          /* filename.O */
```

IIUC, these files are simply backups of old settings. As such, they
should be safe to remove.